# Excel2Latex Table too wide and too long

Tags: excel, excel2latex

I have a long (36 rows) and wide (15 columns) excel table and I am using excel2latex. I am having issues to adjust the width and length of it. I want the table to continue in the following pages (in order to adjust the length), and need to adjust the letter or to find a way for the table to continue in another page (in order to adjust the width). 
Is this possible? I am using footnote size. 
Thanks a lot for your help!
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
%\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{landscape}
    %\setlength{tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \footnotesize
    %\begin{small}
 % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\vspace*{-1.5cm}
\caption{example}\\
 \hspace*{-5pt}\begin{tabular}{c{1cm\textwidth}p{5cm\textwidth}p{4cm\textwidth}p{2cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}p{1.5cm\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxx} & \textbf{fffff} & \textbf{uuuuu} & \textbf{zzzz} & \textbf{oooo} & \textbf{nnn} & \textbf{date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Date3} & \textbf{Date4} & \textbf{pppp} & \textbf{vvvv} & \textbf{ssss} \\
     \midrule
     No    & 1     & x     & xxx   & Ddddd & Yes   & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxx  & Ddddd & Yes   & Oct-07 & Today & Mar-11 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-08 & Dec-09 & Apr-09 & Dec-09 &       &       &  \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes   & Mar-07 & Mar-10 & Mar-07 & Mar-10 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    & Jan-08 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    & Feb-11 & Today & Feb-11 & Jun-11 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     &       & Mmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    & Apr-02 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-06 & Dec-11 & Oct-06 & Dec-11 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-04 & Jun-13 & Jan-04 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Jun-13 & Oct-05 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-12 & Dec-13 & Jan-12 & Dec-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-80 & Today & Jan-80 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mommmmm & Yes   & Feb-03 & Today & Feb-03 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   &       & Apr-12 &       & Apr-12 & 0     &       &  \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Today & Oct-05 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmm & Yes   & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-13 & Today & Jul-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmm & Yes   & Jan-68 & Mar-08 & Jan-68 & Mar-08 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmmm & Yes   & May-11 & Oct-15 & May-11 & Oct-15 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-5pt}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
%\end{small}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Example for Salim:

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
 \usepackage{tabularx}%
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
%\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{landscape}
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        %\footnotesize
        \centering
        \vspace*{-1.5cm}
        \caption{example}
        \hspace*{-5pt}\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{xxxx} & \textbf{fffff} & \textbf{uuuuu} & \textbf{zzzz} & \textbf{oooo} & \textbf{nnn} & \textbf{date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Date3} & \textbf{Date4} & \textbf{pppp} & \textbf{vvvv} & \textbf{ssss} \\
        \midrule
        No    & 1     & x     & xxx   & dddd  & Yes   & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxx  & ddddd & Yes   & Oct-07 & Today & Mar-11 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-08 & Dec-09 & Apr-09 & Dec-09 &       &       &  \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Mar-07 & Mar-10 & Mar-07 & Mar-10 &       &       & A ball is a round, usually spherical but sometimes ovoid, object with various uses. It is used in ball games, where the play of the game follows the state of the ball as it is hit, kicked or thrown by players. In the context of sports, "ball" need not refer to a spherical object, as is the case in American football. Balls can also be used for simpler activities, such as catch, marbles and juggling. Balls made from hard-wearing materials are used in engineering applications to provide very low friction bearings, known as ball bearings. Black-powder weapons use stone and metal balls as p \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    & Jan-08 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
        & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    & Feb-11 & Today & Feb-11 & Jun-11 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   &  \\
        & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     &       & mmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & No    & Apr-02 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
        & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
        & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
        & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-06 & Dec-11 & Oct-06 & Dec-11 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-04 & Jun-13 & Jan-04 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     & A ball is a round, usually spherical but sometimes ovoid, object with various uses. It is used in ball games, where the play of the game follows the state of the ball as it is hit, kicked or thrown by players. In the context of sports, "ball" need not refer to a spherical object, as is the case in American football. Balls can also be used for simpler activities, such as catch, marbles and juggling. Balls made from hard-wearing materials are used in engineering applications to provide very low friction bearings, known as ball bearings. Black-powder weapons use stone and metal balls as p & mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Jun-13 & Oct-05 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-12 & Dec-13 & Jan-12 & Dec-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-80 & Today & Jan-80 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Feb-03 & Today & Feb-03 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   &       & Apr-12 &       & Apr-12 & 0     &       &  \\
        Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Today & Oct-05 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-13 & Today & Jul-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-68 & Mar-08 & Jan-68 & Mar-08 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        No    & 2     & x     &       & mmmmmm & Yes   & May-11 & Oct-15 & May-11 & Oct-15 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}\hspace*{-5pt}%
        \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
    %\end{sidewaystable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you post a shortened example of the code you're working with?

Comment: Mi Hico, yes, sorry about this. Here an example...

Comment: `p{5cm}` instead of  `p{5cm\textwidth}`.

Comment: Hi Salim, I tried that and the same problem...

Comment: What can I add to continue length of the table and the width in another page? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is the following: when I have many information in each cell, the table is cut on the right and on the low side of the page and does not continue in the following page. I need to find a way in order the table to continue in the following page. I tried everything I found here and did not work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the tool `excel2latex` is that usually the resulting LaTeX tables have to be reworked.

In your case just use package `longtable` as showed in the following MWE. Please see that I copied your table lines after the `\midrule` to get a longer table to get two pages.  Please see the definition of `\firstendhead` and `\endhead`. `@{}` is used to have no empty space besides the table. And please see the pretty printed table code (in this way you can better see missing values etc).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%\setlength{tabcolsep}{5pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}@{}}
\caption{example}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxx} & \textbf{fffff} & \textbf{uuuuu} & \textbf{zzzz} & \textbf{oooo} & \textbf{nnn} & \textbf{date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Date3} & \textbf{Date4} & \textbf{pppp} & \textbf{vvvv} & \textbf{ssss} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{13}{@{}c@{}}{table continued~\dots}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxx} & \textbf{fffff} & \textbf{uuuuu} & \textbf{zzzz} & \textbf{oooo} & \textbf{nnn} & \textbf{date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Date3} & \textbf{Date4} & \textbf{pppp} & \textbf{vvvv} & \textbf{ssss} \\
\midrule
\endhead
No  & 1     & x     & xxx             & Ddddd   & Yes & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxx            & Ddddd   & Yes & Oct-07 & Today  & Mar-11 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxx   & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jul-08 & Dec-09 & Apr-09 & Dec-09 &       &     &  \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Apr-13 & Today  & Apr-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Apr-13 & Today  & Apr-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes & Mar-07 & Mar-10 & Mar-07 & Mar-10 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  & Jan-08 & Today  & -      & -      & 0     & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  &        &        &        &        &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  & Feb-11 & Today  & Feb-11 & Jun-11 & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  & Jan-07 & Today  & -      & -      & 0     & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
Yes & 1     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  & No  & Jan-07 & Today  & -      & -      &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  & Apr-02 & Today  & -      & -      &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-06 & Dec-11 & Oct-06 & Dec-11 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes & Jan-04 & Jun-13 & Jan-04 & Jun-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-05 & Jun-13 & Oct-05 & Jun-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jan-12 & Dec-13 & Jan-12 & Dec-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jan-80 & Today  & Jan-80 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mommmmm & Yes & Feb-03 & Today  & Feb-03 & Today  & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes &        & Apr-12 &        & Apr-12 & 0     &     &  \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-05 & Today  & Oct-05 & Today  & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmm     & Yes & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jul-13 & Today  & Jul-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmm   & Yes & Jan-68 & Mar-08 & Jan-68 & Mar-08 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmm   &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mm      &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmm     &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmm   &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmm    &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmm     &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  & Yes & May-11 & Oct-15 & May-11 & Oct-15 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
\midrule
No  & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxx   & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jul-08 & Dec-09 & Apr-09 & Dec-09 &       &     &  \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Apr-13 & Today  & Apr-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Apr-13 & Today  & Apr-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes & Mar-07 & Mar-10 & Mar-07 & Mar-10 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  & Jan-08 & Today  & -      & -      & 0     & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  &        &        &        &        &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  & Feb-11 & Today  & Feb-11 & Jun-11 & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  & Jan-07 & Today  & -      & -      & 0     & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No  &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
Yes & 1     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  & No  & Jan-07 & Today  & -      & -      &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & No  & Apr-02 & Today  & -      & -      &       & Yes & yyyyyyyyy \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       & Yes &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-06 & Dec-11 & Oct-06 & Dec-11 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes & Jan-04 & Jun-13 & Jan-04 & Jun-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-05 & Jun-13 & Oct-05 & Jun-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jan-12 & Dec-13 & Jan-12 & Dec-13 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jan-80 & Today  & Jan-80 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mommmmm & Yes & Feb-03 & Today  & Feb-03 & Today  & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes &        & Apr-12 &        & Apr-12 & 0     &     &  \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Oct-05 & Today  & Oct-05 & Today  & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmm     & Yes & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & 0     &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
Yes & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm  & Yes & Jul-13 & Today  & Jul-13 & Today  &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmm   & Yes & Jan-68 & Mar-08 & Jan-68 & Mar-08 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmm   &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mm      &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmm     &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmm   &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmm    &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmm     &     &        &        &        &        &       &     &  \\
No  & 2     & x     &                 & Mmmmmm  & Yes & May-11 & Oct-15 & May-11 & Oct-15 &       &     & yyyyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your table like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
%\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{landscape}
   % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\footnotesize
\centering
\vspace*{-1.5cm}
\caption{example}
 \hspace*{-5pt}\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxx} & \textbf{fffff} & \textbf{uuuuu} & \textbf{zzzz} & \textbf{oooo} & \textbf{nnn} & \textbf{date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Date3} & \textbf{Date4} & \textbf{pppp} & \textbf{vvvv} & \textbf{ssss} \\
     \midrule
     No    & 1     & x     & xxx   & Ddddd & Yes   & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & Nov-07 & Aug-12 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxx  & Ddddd & Yes   & Oct-07 & Today & Mar-11 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-08 & Dec-09 & Apr-09 & Dec-09 &       &       &  \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Apr-13 & Today & Apr-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes   & Mar-07 & Mar-10 & Mar-07 & Mar-10 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    & Jan-08 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    & Feb-11 & Today & Feb-11 & Jun-11 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     & 0     & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & No    &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     &       & Mmmmmm & No    & Jan-07 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & No    & Apr-02 & Today & -     & -     &       & Yes   & yyyyyyyyy \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     & 1     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       & Yes   &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-06 & Dec-11 & Oct-06 & Dec-11 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-04 & Jun-13 & Jan-04 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Jun-13 & Oct-05 & Jun-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-12 & Dec-13 & Jan-12 & Dec-13 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jan-80 & Today & Jan-80 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mommmmm & Yes   & Feb-03 & Today & Feb-03 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   &       & Apr-12 &       & Apr-12 & 0     &       &  \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Oct-05 & Today & Oct-05 & Today & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmm & Yes   & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & Jan-75 & Dec-13 & 0     &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     Yes   & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmmm & Yes   & Jul-13 & Today & Jul-13 & Today &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmm & Yes   & Jan-68 & Mar-08 & Jan-68 & Mar-08 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Mmmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmm &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
     No    & 2     & x     &       & Mmmmmm & Yes   & May-11 & Oct-15 & May-11 & Oct-15 &       &       & yyyyyyyyy \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-5pt}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Salim, yes, that is what I want, but the problem is that when I have a long text in some of the cells, then the table does not continue in the other page. Here an example... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have just edited the post with the example, thanks!